# Unable to open AWS Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am currently working on a machine learning project and choose to build, train and deploy my model using AWS Sagemaker. I have been able to open Sagemaker studio for the past few days but now when I try I get the error below:

> Unable to create app [default] for user [ ] in domain [ ]. Reason: Resource limits for this account have been exceeded. Please contact Customer Support for assistance.

[image]

I think I am supposed to increase my quota allocation but I do not know for which Sagemaker quota. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got my problem resolved. Turns out AWS put my account on hold pending verification. Once I submitted the relevant documents, AWS reviewed my account and removed the temporary hold.